# Error in packing 128 byte structure using Struct in python

Tags: python

I want to pack 128 byte of different data types.  The structure as follows

4 bytes - 0x12345678,

2 bytes - 0x1234,

120 bytes - 0x00 (repeats 120 times),

2 byte - 0x99 ,

I tried with below code but fails

```
struct.pack('<LH120BH',0x12345678,0x1234,0x00,0x99 )
```

gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
struct.pack('<LH120BH',0x12345678,0x1234,0x00,0x99 )
struct.error: pack expected 123 items for packing (got 4)
```

pls help me.  Thanks in advane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to pack `0x00` in to an array if you want it to repeat 120 times and unpack it when call `struct.pack`, maybe something like this:

`struct.pack('<LH120BH',0x12345678,0x1234,*[0x00] * 120,0x99)`